# How to use Context paramater with acceptCall function?

Tags: android

I have tried to add some the functions to class so I can open incoming calls, but I have a problem occurring in the passing of the parameter "Context"

[image]

```
package com.bitgriff.androidcalls;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallHelper {

    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;
    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;
    /*
    public Context context;


    private CallHelper(Context context) {

        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();

    }
*/
    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls.
     */

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }


    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                //Not work
                acceptCall(Context ctx);
                //----------------------//--------------------------------
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Incoming: "+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void acceptCall(Context context){
        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }


/*
    private void rejectCall(Context context)
    {
        Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON); buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }
    */
    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx,
                    "Outgoing: "+number,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't put the type of the variable next to the parameter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either don't put `Context`

```
acceptCall(ctx);
```

Or cast it

```
acceptCall((Context) ctx);
```

---

This is not valid syntax.

```
acceptCall(Context ctx);
```